# Does Laravel sets the $errors variable in login page to null authomatically?

Tags: laravel-8

I applied laravel/breeze authentication to provide forms and controllers for authentication. Then I created a custom package named "admin" and followed similar views, layers and components for admin authentication in admin package. All things are right but when I want to route to login for admin I reach the error

$errors is undefined

Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $errors }} with {{ $errors ?? '' }}

While when routing to login page of user in breeze all things are right.

Then I changed

```
public function createLogin(){

    return view($this->_config['view']);
}
```

to

```
public function createLogin(){

    //I chained withErrors() function and worked surprisingly! 
    return view($this->_config['view'])->withErrors(null);
}
```

for admin login page and the problem solved. Now my question is that does Laravel sets the $errors variable in login page to null authomatically? and How? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in Laravel documentations. "An $errors variable is shared with all of your application's views by the Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession middleware, which is provided by the web middleware group. When this middleware is applied an $errors variable will always be available in your views, allowing you to conveniently assume the $errors variable is always defined and can be safely used. The $errors variable will be an instance of Illuminate\Support\MessageBag".